# Zend, Global variable in Application.ini?

Tags: zend-framework, global-variables

I have a question as I need to have a global static variable and I have question is any possibility to add it to the application.ini file, how to do it?

Or I have to:

1. Create abstract class with static variable,
2. Register it in Zend_Registry to have access to this variable from all application (Register it in Bootstrap file)
3. I can use it, or there is easier, I mean "automatic way" to do it?

Thanks for  advice!
Regars,

Comment: The configuration files are meant to be used to specify parameters, used as inputs for your application. You should not be adding anything programmatically

Answer (score 13):

in Application.ini file

```
someservice.apikey  = 12345678
someservice.passkey = 87654321
```

in bootstrap

```
public function _initSomeservice()
{
    $someservice = $this->getOption('someservice');
    Zend_Registry::set('someservice', $someservice);
}
```

to pull from Registry

```
$config = Zend_Registry::get('someservice');
```

Answer (score 6):

The best solution for me was to create a variable in index.php file. I have added:
defined('VARIABLE_NAME')
    || define('VARIABLE_NAME', 'Something here');

And now I can access to it from everywhere ;D
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't use the Zend_Registry nor constants, for two reasons

1. In the registry you are never sure what happened with the variables. Every part of the application can change them and you wouldn't be noticed. I see the registry actually as an anit-pattern.
2. Constants are polluting your application unnecessarily. What if you use for every configuration some constant? You have to keep an additional document with all the constants defined, it's horrible to maintain.

What the best option is, is to directly get the config object from the bootstrap. In next examples, I assume you have this in your application.ini:

```
someservice.apikey  = 12345678
someservice.passkey = 87654321
```

The bootstrap is set as a parameter in the frontController. If you have an action controller, this makes it as simple as this:

```
$serviceOptions = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getOption('someservice');
```

If you have a service instantiated in your controller, you now can pass them on through the constructor and/or setter.

If you want to get the options not within your controller, but somewhere else, you can use the singleton pattern the frontController implements. So at any place (of course only during dispatching, not during the bootstrap itself) you're able to do this:

```
$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$serviceOptions  = $frontController->getParam('bootstrap')
                                   ->getOption('someservice');
```

With above method you're safe you have always the right configuration option and not some possibly mutated one.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify value in the application.ini and in the Bootsrap.php you read it and save in Zend_Registry. You can also use PHP define method to create constants (if you veriable is constant).

Comment: +1 on simply using PHP globals. Therefore bypassing need for Zend static class access in a View.

Answer (score 0):

I just added  define('VARIABLE_NAME', 'Something here'); to bootstrap. 
Instant global constants.

These constants were placed inside of a protected _intiFuncName  function inside of the bootstrap extends class

Answer (score 0):

I have a series of constants with the following naming convention in application.ini:

```
system.image_path  = "/assets/images"
system.custom_path = "/assets/custom"
system.cdn_URL     = "http://cdnurl.com"
```

And I just reference them in my code as if they were PHP constants:

```
SYSTEM_IMAGE_PATH
SYSTEM_CUSTOM_PATH
SYSTEM_CDN_URL
```